# Requests library - login to SM based forums

Tags: python

im trying to program in python a bot which needs to login to SM based forum and im having problems to login using "Requests" library.
the login page is exactly as this one :

```
https://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?action=login2
```

and this is my code:

```
header = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'
}

login_data = {
    'user': 'username',
    'passwrd':'password',
    'cookielength': 'cookielength',
    'hash_passwrd': 'passwordhash'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    url = "https://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?action=login2"
    r = s.get(url, headers=header)
    r = s.post(url,data = login_data,headers=header)
    file = open("test.html", "w")
    file.write(r.text)
```

hash_password is set to the value i have intercept from the POST request while i logged in.

any idea why the login failed?
thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, how do you know your password hash?

Comment: i logged in normally and intercepted the POST request , inside i found the hash_passwrd value

Comment: You might need to also pass the `ea27964f9` data field?

Comment: where is that? i cant find it in the login source code page

Comment: If you inspect the network call on Chrome, you'll notice that under the data fileds passed section when you click on the login button